# How to remove windshield wiper-scratch?

Tags: windshield-wipers, windshield

Not realizing that the windshield cleaner fluid is near empty I wiped the windshield with few drops of fluid, as the windshield was dirty, the wiper wiped the dry dust against the windshield and that left the windshield with few minor scratches along the wiper path. Although the scratches are not that visible enough, in night it causes distractions. Already replaced the wipers as they were near the end of their life. I have polishing compound to polish clear-coat damage, can I use this to remove the scratches or by any other method?

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that dust from the wipers scratched the glass, have you tried cleaning it thoroughly with a glass cleaner and non-abrasive cloth?

Comment: yes have tried those, I think the wiper was dying so it could have happened before and I might have noticed that on that day as I don't often drive at night

Comment: Some light scratches can be buffed out. Just like your paint. [For example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVUtdlzrktI)

Comment: @Granny the video you provided shows use of specialized tools and glass buffing pads which I don't have access to

Comment: @Nilabja And a local shop near you?

Comment: I am not going to buy polishing machine just to remove scratches that occurs rarely, Although I can look for only glass buffing pads and use it(not available in local autoparts store, advised me to look at furniture store that I could not due to rain ). I am looking for a solution that I can do from home, I am not willing to go to some specialist. @Granny

Comment: @Nilabja Even though you are not willing to go to a specialist, if you mess up even further with your DIY method, you may need to replace the windshield or go to a specialist anyway who will have to fix it even more than before. I dont suggest doing a DIY job without the proper recourses. But whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66863/discussion-between-nilabja-and-granny).