# Removing wiper scratches from windshield (light scratches but annoying in night with lights)

Tags: windshield-wipers, windshield

[I found a similar question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/48602/37650) but it was not answered, I was traveling in night and there was some light sandstorm that made the windshield unclear I then tried using the wipers but it seems this caused some light scratches in the windshield.

The scratches are light (my nail doesn't get stuck in them) but they are very annoying in night driving making the lights spread and annoy me.

Is there any way to remove these scratches without replacing the windshield? I didn't find the original windshield for sale & others I am afraid might not be safe & won't withstand the supreme temperature here so I very much prefer fixing it myself.

Can anyone advise how to remove these scratches?

Notes:

1- My wipers are old but still working fine, I wonder if their dryness be a cause for the scratches, but the most important thing now & goal of this question is removing the scratches

2- My wipers type [is that heavier than average one](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Holden-VE-Commodore-Windscreen-Wiper-Blades-A-Pair-/301269432584)

Update:

I tried cleaning the windshield thoroughly & I tried to clean it using toothpaste but still the scratches didn't improve.

Comment: That similar question contained an answer in one of the comments - did you check?

Comment: Sure, I saw it but there is no decisive answer, there is a recommendation to clean the windshield thoroughly which I did 

They also continued discussion in chat which is not available, so I am asking maybe someone solved this & can advise me

Comment: So you missed the bit that pointed out buffing with compound...

Comment: You mean the video, right? I have the same response like the other question owner: "the video you provided shows use of specialized tools and glass buffing pads which I don't have access to"

I don't have these special tools & unfortunately I can't find a workshop that have it here ...

I hope someone could solve it in an easier way

Comment: Jeweller’s rouge and a large tin of elbow grease.... if not you are left with buy a new one.

Comment: Thanks Solar, you mean one of them, right? but I wonder if that would stick, I mean when I clean the windshield I think all of it will be lost , what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the scratches by replacing the windshield. Removing them by polishing is theoretically possibly but impractical/time consuming. I tried , at the time I had access to various grades of diamond  polishing compounds ( and any silicon carbide grade ). Even working on a small area I found the time /work was unreasonable. Using a power polisher would be better but one would need hundred+ of dollars worth of diamond polishing paste.